# Why did this happen between Vargo Hoat and Ser Harys?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

> "After the hanged men had stopped kicking, Vargo Hoat and Ser Harys embraced and kissed and swore to love each other always as Lord Tywin looked on".
>
> <sub>A Clash of Kings, Arya VII</sub>

I'm having some trouble with this sentence. Why did they kiss and hug?

Comment: Many people hug and kiss after an argument as a sign of forbearance toward one another. And in this case it was done to either a) Appease Tywin or b) was invoked by Tywin as a means of psychological tactic (I see you guys hate each-other, it would be a shame if you had to hug and kiss one another right now)!

Comment: Even today many cultures have men kissing each other's cheeks as a form of greeting between close friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of this happens in [Chapter 30 of A Clash of Kings](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_30). From the summary in the linked page:

> On their first night, Ser Harys Swyft’s squire is killed and two of the Bloody Mummers are wounded. Tywin hangs both along with one of Lord Lewys Lydden’s archers who is supposed to have started the trouble.

Since Tywin was looking on after the men were hanged, he probably forced Vargo Hoat and Ser Harys to reconcile with each other. He might also be trying to shame them in order to keep them, and the rest of his forces, in line.